# Quanteda: display the actual difference between texts

Tags: difference, similarity, quanteda

I managed to calculate the difference between two texts with the cosine method. With the following:

```
    library("quanteda")
dfmat <- corpus_subset(corpusnew) %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_remove(stopwords("portuguese")) %>%
    dfm()
(tstat1 <- textstat_simil(dfmat, method = "cosine", margin = "documents"))
as.matrix(tstat1)
```

And I get the following matrix:

```
       text1 text2 text3 text4 text5 
text1 1.000 0.801 0.801 0.801 0.798
```

However, I would like to know **the actual words that account for the difference** and **not** by how much they differ or are alike. Is there a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about comparing tokens using `setdiff()`?

```r
require(quanteda)
toks <- tokens(corpus(c("a b c d", "a e")))
toks
#> Tokens consisting of 2 documents.
#> text1 :
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
#> 
#> text2 :
#> [1] "a" "e"

setdiff(toks[[1]], toks[[2]])
#> [1] "b" "c" "d"
setdiff(toks[[2]], toks[[1]])
#> [1] "e"
```

Comment: Hi @KoheiWatanabe ,  I think this is probably it.

Answer (score 0):

This question only has pairwise answers, since each computation of similarity occurs between a single pair of documents. It's also not entirely clear what output you want to see, so I'll take my best guess and demonstrate a few possibilities.

So if you wanted to the features most different between text1 and text2, for instance, you could slice the documents you want to compare from the dfm, and then change `margin = "features"` to get the similarity of the document across features.

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 3.2.1
#> Unicode version: 13.0
#> ICU version: 69.1
#> Parallel computing: 10 of 10 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

dfmat <- tokens(data_corpus_inaugural[1:5], remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_remove(stopwords("en")) %>%
    dfm()

library("quanteda.textstats")
sim <- textstat_simil(dfmat[1:2, ], margin = "features", method = "cosine")
```

Now we can examine the pairwise similarities (greatest and smallest) by converting the similarity matrix to a data.frame, and sorting it.

```r
# most similar features
as.data.frame(sim) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(cosine)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(cosine < 1) %>%
    head(10)
#>    feature1   feature2    cosine
#> 1   present        may 0.9994801
#> 2   country        may 0.9994801
#> 3       may government 0.9991681
#> 4   present   citizens 0.9988681
#> 5   country   citizens 0.9988681
#> 6   present     people 0.9988681
#> 7   country     people 0.9988681
#> 8   present     united 0.9988681
#> 9   country     united 0.9988681
#> 10  present government 0.9973337
    
# most different features
as.data.frame(sim) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(cosine) %>%
    head(10)
#>      feature1   feature2    cosine
#> 1  government       upon 0.1240347
#> 2  government      chief 0.1240347
#> 3  government magistrate 0.1240347
#> 4  government     proper 0.1240347
#> 5  government     arrive 0.1240347
#> 6  government   endeavor 0.1240347
#> 7  government    express 0.1240347
#> 8  government       high 0.1240347
#> 9  government      sense 0.1240347
#> 10 government  entertain 0.1240347
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

There are other ways to compare the words most different between documents, such as "keyness" - for instance `quanteda.textstats::textstat_keyness()` between text1 and text2, where the head and tail of the resulting data.frame will tell you the most dissimilar features.